# Cassandra availability penalty in strong consistency mode

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

as I got Cassandra has ALL consistency level. It provides: "the highest consistency and the lowest availability". If this level provides strong consistency?

What availability penalty for it? I don't see a case when data won't be availabile. Could anyone give example of a such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a consistency level of ALL then the coordinator must receive a response from all nodes. This means that:

- After a successful write, nobody will read the previous state (high consistency).
- If even a single node fails to respond, the whole read/write operation will fail (low availability).

For further reading, see the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

---

> Could anyone give example of a such case.

- A node is disconnected for maintenance.
- A node crashes.
- The power goes out in the server room / datacentre.
- A node becomes unresponsive due to high load.
- The network connection to a node goes down or becomes too slow.
- Data has not yet propagated to all nodes.

Comment: The examples hint at this but the answer doesn't come right out and say that CL=ALL is a toy and a teaching tool. NO ONE uses it in production for real applications and it would be crazy to do so since even a single node being slow/down would cause query errors. Using LOCAL_QUORUM for both reads and writes gives you in practical terms the same amount of consistency but with sane availability tradeoffs (>half the replicas in each replica-set need to be responsive).